# How to change Morris Chart's data dynamically in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I change data values dynamically, like if I make changes in one JavaScript file, the values linked with this file automatically change?

```
$('#new').click(function(){
  goodComments++;
  badComments++;
  neutralComments++;
});
```

Whenever I click on the 'new' button I get updated values of 'goodComments', 'badComments', 'neutralComments' in the script given below. This script will run only once, that's why I want to change data parameters dynamically.

```
<script>
Morris.Bar({
            element: 'bar-example',
            data: [
                { y: 'Comment Types', a:goodComments, b: badComments, c:neutralComments },
            ],
            xkey: 'y',
            ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            labels: ['Good Comment', 'Bad Comment', 'Neutral Comment']
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

So you have first to get a instance of the `Morris.Bar` chart:

```
var G = Morris.Bar(options);
```

you pass along the chart options object. This object will come with a `data` section that needs to be updated, so we create a `updateData` function to return this data structure as the variable that we need to update:

```
function updateData() {
    return [{
      y: 'Comment Types',
      a: goodComments,
      b: badComments,
      c: neutralComments
    }];
  }
```

So that we can create a options object like:

```
var options = {
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: updateData(),
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    labels: ['Good Comment', 'Bad Comment', 'Neutral Comment']
  }
```

We now attach the event to the click button where when fired, the variables values will be updated and the new data will be passed to the chart using the `setData` method:

```
$('#new').click(function() {
    goodComments++;
    badComments++;
    neutralComments++;
    G.setData( updateData() );
  });
```

So every time this event is fired, the counters are updated and the chart backed by `G` variable will be updated by `setData`.

You can now try the result here. Click the button to see values changing in the labels and in the chart.

```js
  var goodComments = 0,
    badComments = 3,
    neutralComments = 1,
    G;

  function updateData() {
    return [{
      y: 'Comment Types',
      a: goodComments,
      b: badComments,
      c: neutralComments
    }];
  }

  $('#new').click(function() {
    goodComments++;
    badComments++;
    neutralComments++;
    //console.log(goodComments, badComments, neutralComments)
    G.setData(updateData());
  });

  var G = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: updateData(),
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    labels: ['Good Comment', 'Bad Comment', 'Neutral Comment']
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Morris.js Bar Chart Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bar-example"></div>
  <button id="new">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It will redraw the whole chart again or it will update the current one?

Comment: it will update the data in the current chart, if you take care to do not create every time the `bar` object, since a `Morris.Bar` instance is backed by this.

Comment: Its not updating values :(

Comment: @user3466165 fixed it and provided a working code example.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.